# ReactJS rerenders more than twice when fetching data from API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

why does my page renders twice, then after fetching data from api, it will re-render again twice. here's my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import axios from "axios"
function Pokemon()
{
    const [pokeList,setPokeList] = useState([]);    

    useEffect(()=>{     
        console.log('useState-mounted')     
        axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151")        
        .then((response) => {
            setPokeList(response.data.results);
        })      
    },[])

    const generationOnePokemon = pokeList.map(i => {
        return <h3 key={i.url}>{i.name}</h3>
    })

    return(
        <>          
            <h1>Shop</h1>
            {console.log('page-rendered')}
            {generationOnePokemon}
        </>
    )
}

export default Pokemon
```

Result from console

[image: Result from console]

Comment: Are you using `React.StrictMode` somewhere up the tree?

Comment: @Linschlager yes, ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Pokemon />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour when using `<React.StrictMode>`. It only happens in development mode, so there are no production implications with this.
It ensures that your `setState` calls are properly implemented and do not rely on only being executed once.

You can read more about React StrictMode [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).